# In the CLT for sample averages, why is there a square root on $n$ in $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$?

Tags: statistics

My knowledge of statistics and mathematics is too limited to understand the proof of the CLT, but is it nonetheless possible to understand why the denominator contains a square root of $n$?

Why is it not simply $n$ (or something else for that matter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$
When $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent, then
$$
\var(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \var(X_1)+\cdots+\var(X_n).
$$
If the variances are all equal to $\sigma^2$, this is $n\sigma^2$.

And
$$
\var\left( \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{n^2}\var(X_1+\cdots+X_n) = \frac{1}{n^2} n\sigma^2= \frac{\sigma^2}{n}.
$$
Now find the standard deviation of $\dfrac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{n}$.